# Cannot get Sharepoint 2016 Search working

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have already posted this over at Technet but haven't made any progress so am hoping there are some gurus on here that can help?

This is the technet thread:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/acd0de63-1144-46cf-abec-bb20f9f85356/sharepoint-2016-search-sorry-something-went-wrong?forum=SP2016#bd80218d-c363-4e41-abb8-7c94d3e30078

Basically one of our clients Sharepoint 2016 Search Service simply will not work.

I have removed, tidied as best I can and reinstalled but we always get the same error "Sorry Something Went Wrong".

As you will see on the technet thread I have been through the ULS logs but they don't give me anything useful.

Can anyone help?

Happy to provide more ULS logs if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. If you have multiple servers in SharePoint farm, make sure all servers have the same date and time settings.
2. Go to IIS->Connections -> Sites -> YourSite->Click Authentication > Enable anonymous authentication.
3. Remove the SharePoint server from the SharePoint farm and re-add.
4. Go to services on computer-> right click on the “SharePoint Server Search 16” service-> select properties-> log on tab -> re-enter the user name & password of domain user->restart the “SharePoint Server Search 16” service.
5. Re-run the SharePoint 2016 products configuration wizard and check the result.
6. Repair the SharePoint 2016 product. Go to control panel->right click “Microsoft SharePoint server 2016”->click Repair.

More references:

SharePoint 2013 Search Stopped Working.

http://blog.tippoint.net/sharepoint-2013-search-stopped-working/

Error: There was no endpoint listening at.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166246/Error-There-was-no-endpoint-listening-at

Search not working in SharePoint 2013 RTM.

https://mahindragupta.wordpress.com/tag/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-net-tcp/

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I tried them all but no change unfortunately.

Sharepoint Product configuration completes successfully.

Sharepoint 2016 repair fails - "can't find the required files"

Anonymous authentication is already enabled

There are no other sharepoint servers - this is the only one. Not sure if I can still remove it from the farm?

Time and date matches DC and is correct.